# how to get two different value in one row where table and column is same

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get both the user who sends the message to other and who receive the message in one row in each row.

```
UserTable
==================================
userId    userName
-------   ---------
23         Name1
24         Name2
25         Name3

Message Table
==================================================
msgId      senderId       reciverId      messsage
-------    ----------     ----------     -------------
2          24             25              blah
3          25             24              ohh really blah
4          23             24              lets do blah



Output I need

msgId      sender       receiver         message
--------   -------      ----------      ---------
2          Name2         Name3           blah
3          Name3         Name2           Ohh really blah
4          Name1         Name2           lets do blah
```

So what should be oracle sql query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just join the `UserTable` to the `Message` table twice:

```
SELECT
    m.msgId,
    u1.userName AS sender,
    u2.userName AS receiver,
    m.message
FROM Message m
INNER JOIN UserTable u1
    ON m.senderId = u1.userId
INNER JOIN UserTable u2
    ON m.reciverId = u2.userId;
```

Comment: Is that possible to use one instance only of UserTable like      "u1.userName AS sender,
             u1.userName AS receiver".  And then use or condition in ON of inner join! @Tim

Comment: No, I don't think that would work (or is desirable).  You need to match two user IDs, so you need two separate joins.  Nothing wrong with my answer, by the way, if you tune the query etc.